# How to keep New Line when pulling data from SQL into Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2010

I have an Access DB that is using SQL to store the data that it presents.

When a user inputs data into one of the note fields they use several lines to show the difference in the date or time when they entered the notes. So that it will look something like this:

```
8/24: ttu scheduled for 8/28
8/22: pending dispatch for pretest
8/21: ckt in prog
8/18: installed, ckt in prog
8/14: installation in progress, need terminal information loaded into Varasset
8/7: pending COEI install and transport
7/25: osp complete, ready for coei
7/18: osp still in construction
7/10: osp still in construction
6/19: osp in progress  
6/16: not started   
6/2: 100% material, pending osp material, no permit needed   
5/31: pending material  
5/22:pending material and state permit  
5/16: pending material  
4/10: infinium approved  
4/4: adding project per gate approval on 4/3
```

Then Access will send this to the SQL table. Then the next time that the user opens the Access DB the notes look like this:

```
8/24: ttu scheduled for 8/288/22: pending dispatch for pretest8/21: ckt in prog8/18: installed, ckt in prog8/14: installation in progress, need terminal information loaded into Varasset8/7: pending COEI install and transport7/25: osp complete, ready for coei7/18: osp still in construction7/10: osp still in construction6/19: osp in progress  6/16: not started   6/2: 100% material, pending osp material, no permit needed   5/31: pending material  5/22:pending material and state permit  5/16: pending material  4/10: infinium approved  4/4: adding project per gate approval on 4/3
```

How can I keep the New Lines when pulling the data from SQL into Access?

**Addition**

Here is what the property sheet of the Meeting_Notes looks like:
[image: Meeting_Notes Property Sheet]

I tried adding `=Replace([MEETING_NOTES],Chr(13),Chr(13) & Chr(10))` to the `Before Update` Event for the notes field, but the end user says that this did not fix the problem. All the notes still end up as just one long line instead of having them broke up with New Lines.

Comment: maybe build the query with extra {CR}  `char(10)`, and also you could check the result in `text` not in `grid` to see what is the actual result looks like

Comment: This is unusual. How exactly are you storing and retrieving the data? If you use linked tables and bound forms, this should not happen.

Comment: @LONG I get different results depending on whether I use SSMS 2012 or 2014. But that isn't the problem. The problem is when Access shows the data.

Comment: @Andre The tables are linked tables using ODBC. The forms are bound. I agree this should not happen.

Comment: If you are using bound forms and a bound text box, this should just work. Are you constructing an insert statement, or letting Access do that for you? What is the Text Format property of the Text Box set to?

Comment: Can you try to do this on the BeforeUpdate event? =Replace(Me.[MyField],Chr(13), Chr(13) & Chr(10))

Comment: @DanielG I am not constructing the insert I'm letting Access figure that out. I know that it inserts it into the SQL table with the new lines, but then it doesn't pull the data with the line breaks.

Comment: Sorry for all of the questions, lol, but are users typing in the value into MEETING_NOTES, or is it being set by code?

Comment: @DanielG I'll see if I can add that.

Comment: Or set the Control Source to the expression as opposed to only the field. ie. ControlSource Property = Replace([MEETING_NOTES],Chr(13), Chr(13) & Chr(10))

Comment: @DanielG I get an error when I have that `REPLACE` in there: >The expression Before Update you entered as the event property setting produced the following error: The object doesn't contain the Automation object 'Me'.

Comment: Try Me!, or just leave the Me. portion out. Me!MEETING_NOTES = Replace([MEETING_NOTES],Chr(13), Chr(13) & Chr(10))

Comment: @DanielG It won't let me get back to `Design View`, just keeps showing that error.

Comment: Hmmm...maybe close the DB and go straight into Design view

Comment: @DanielG I had to undo my changes to the text box first then go back into design view. It looks like this might work. I'll have to play around and see.

Comment: @DanielG If you will put that in an answer I'll mark this as solved. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @DanielG Well shoot, Just heard back again from the end user. It didn't work after all.

Comment: Wow. What happens if you change to a rich text box? There must be something simple we're missing as I have hundreds of forms using the exact same scenario :-)

Comment: Is there any startup code converting it to a Rich Text box? I can replicate the problem when it is set to Rich Text.

Comment: There is no code that converts it to a rich text box. they are just normal text boxes. I'll try changing it and see what happens

Comment: @DanielG It doesn't matter whether it is rich or not it still removes all the new line characters and has everything become just one long line.

Comment: If you wanted to send me an MDF (with sensitive data removed) and a copy of the MDB/ACCDB, I would be happy to try and figure it out for you. I am certain I can figure it out, but unfortunately it's not an obvious fix. :-(